# icon-bar class doesn't display the line in the Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar where there is a hamburger button which comes with the bootstrap
which is

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

but when I remove the`navbar-toggler-icon` class and apply `icon-bar` the button is disappers.But in the console it shows that there is a button a very tiny one. I have added the image for reference.
[image]

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/8m1gyw7t/ this is working fine.

but in that code if I change from `navbar-toggler-icon` to `icon-bar` the button is small and tiny

Comment: Can you please provide a working fiddle?

Comment: check the fiddle @AbhishekPandey

Comment: There is no css rules for `.icon-bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `bootstrap version`, in your fiddle you are using `bootstrap v4-alpha` and the class `icon-bar` no more exist in `v4`.

Now if you want to use `bootstrap v3` classes you need to replace your `bootstrap v4` files with `twitter-bootstrap-v3`.

[CDN LINK](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) for bootstrap v3

and use following code

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I have designed my navbar on v4-alpha,if I use v3 now my navbar is totally different. Is there anyway around to make it work? I tried addinG CSS rules nothing happens.

Comment: I guess this is happening because you haven't changed classes in html yet according to `v3`. If you are in initial phase of your project and not really familiar with `v4`, I would suggest restart your project with `v3` or if you still want to use `v4` then, first call `v3` stylesheet and then `v4` stylesheet. But using both versions is really not a good practice.

Comment: What you have tried?, Please check this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: I know how a navbar works. I told I tried adding v3 first then v4 and tested my site. I still have issues.

Comment: As I said **using both versions is really not a good practice** you will face some issues, the better option is only use `v3` and their classes not `v4`'s classes.

Comment: Yeah Okay. Got that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8m1gyw7t/2/ as you said I have used v3 in this,still I didn;t get those three lines.

Comment: Don not use any 'v4' class in HTML,, for example 'navbar-toggler' instead of 'navbar-toggle'. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8m1gyw7t/3/